# MySQL Complex Where Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to get group names and grouptypes from groups that the user is not in. Everything works before I add the "AND NOT EXISTS" statement in there but I don't want every group, just the ones that the user is not in.

```
Select g.groupName AS groupName, g.groupType AS groupType, COUNT(*) AS total from Groups AS g
JOIN Group_Interest AS gi ON gi.groupId=g.groupId WHERE gi.interestId IN (
     Select interestId FROM User_Interest WHERE userId=214
) AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT groupName FROM Groups AS g JOIN User_Joined_Group AS ujg ON ujg.groupId=g.groupId WHERE userId=214
)
GROUP BY groupName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.   Although your explanation seems clear, it has little resemblance to the query.  Your query returns a count, but that is not mentioned in the question.  Your query has interests, but your question only mentions filtering by user.

Comment: One thing that is confusing (both to me, and probably also to MySQL) is that you top-level query has the "Groups" table aliased as "g" and your sub-query (within the NOT EXISTS) also has the "Groups" table aliased as "g".  For starters, I would ensure that each table has a unique alias - if for no other reason than to avoid visual confusion

Answer (score 0):

This query should work:

```
SELECT g.groupName AS groupName, g.groupType AS groupType, COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM Groups AS g
JOIN Group_Interest AS gi ON gi.groupId = g.groupId 
JOIN User_Interest AS ui ON gi.interestId = ui.interestId
JOIN User_Joined_Group AS ujg ON ujg.groupId = g.groupId
WHERE ui.userId = 214 AND ujg.userId != 214
GROUP BY groupName, groupType
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Your query this way should work too:

```
SELECT g.groupName AS groupName, g.groupType AS groupType, COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM Groups AS g
JOIN Group_Interest AS gi ON gi.groupId = g.groupId 
WHERE gi.interestId IN (
     SELECT interestId FROM User_Interest WHERE userId = 214
) AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 FROM User_Joined_Group AS ujg ON ujg.groupId = g.groupId WHERE ujg.userId = 214)
GROUP BY groupName, groupType
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```